# Why won't my breakpoints work in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator, breakpoints

Qt creator can build and run my projects perfectly, but it will skip straight over any breakpoints I set. I can't find any options to fix this, and I'd appreciate some help.

EDIT: The SDK is built in debug mode, and the project build configuration is set to debug.

Comment: Look at gdb console window, maybe gdb complains about something when loading your app.

Comment: I got no unexpected messages when building from the command prompt.

Comment: No, when in creator, when you start app under the debugger, it should switch into debug panel. There you can show gdb console (it is hidden by default I think, check menus). gdb prints a lot of things there (loaded dlls and so on)

Comment: Are you talking about the Compile Output? It doesn't show any issues except for some unused variables.

Comment: I got it to stop at the breakpoints if I debug the project first, then run it. I'm not sure what this means, but I'm fine with this solution for now...

Comment: lol, I think "debug" project is what you are supposed to do. There are "run with debugging" and "run without debugging" options.

Comment: I had this problem in Qt Creator on Windows. I was using Cygwin's gdb.exe, so I switched over to Microsoft's cdb.exe and this resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Also make sure there is a debugger program selected in your kit.  In QtCreator, Tools | Options | Kits, select kit, Debugger.  I had this problem, and mine was set to "None".  Fortunately, two other ...\cdb.exe's were auto-detected so I chose one of those

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Qt Creator has two modes of running your app: "run" and "debug". I think you may be confused as to what they mean:

- Run: launch the program, exactly the same as double-clicking on the executable.
- Debug: launch the debugger, attach it to the executable, and run the executable through the debugger. This records all steps (function calls etc.) your program has, including breakpoints.

In short: when you need to figure out an internal value during program execution and/or have set breakpoints, use Debug. For anything else, just run it, which is a lot faster.

Comment: In QtCreator 2.3.0, to switch from "release" (doesn't stop debugger at breakpoints) to "debug" you need to click on the project icon --> then click the build pull down --> then you should see "release" and "debug" --> click "debug". The project icon is located in the lower left above the big run, debug, build project GUI icons.

Comment: If you don't switch your project to "debug" then the debugger will always skip your breakpoints. Also make sure to clean after changing to "debug".

Comment: While the above is very true, it does not answer the immediate question - assuming that the run was made correctly under debug mode and with debug session, there are still cases where GDB (but more often CDB) does not stop on break points.    usually this happens after trying to cync the debugger to the process without success.  Unfortunately, I still can't quite figure out why this happen and only on some occasions.

Comment: I don't see a "Build pull down" in "Build Settings". I am in Creator 2.5.2. Is there a new way to switch between building in release and debug mode?

Answer (score 19):

If this is a cmake build, you need to set the build type *before* setting the project, so eg 
in your top CMakeList.txt:

```
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
project(mybuildtype)
```

Officially, you can pass this also to cmake in Projects section when running cmake: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/12694, so with  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug flag, but this does not longer seem to work...
If you want a flag working, you need to test on it before setting the project, see http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2008-September/023808.html

Answer (score 5):

I hope this will help someone who has the same problem.
Even I set it debug mode, but the output files was put on release folder, when I looked at my .pro file, I found this line

```
CONFIG += qt warn_on release rtti exceptions
```

Then I remove "release", then it worked.
Hope this will help.

Comment: I put this lines in the project file (myproject.pro): CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {      CONFIG += qt warn_on rtti exceptions }, After that i've started Debug and it works very well.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add in .pro file next line:

```
CONFIG     += debug
```

And may be you need to delete this:

```
CONFIG     += release
```